# difference inverse(), % in python

Tags: python, cryptography, inverse

I don't know the difference inverse() and % in python. For example `inverse(a, q)`, `a%q`, the result is same, isn't it? (Inverse() is a function belonging to Crypto.Util.number.)

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me the difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's clearly not the same.

```
123%45
# 33

inverse(123, 45)
# 41
```

You can check the [source](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/number.py#L152-L164) of [`inverse`](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Util.number-module.html#inverse) (python 2 code):

```
def inverse(u, v):
    """inverse(u:long, v:long):long
    Return the inverse of u mod v.
    """
    u3, v3 = long(u), long(v)  # python 3: u3, v3 = u, v
    u1, v1 = 1L, 0L            #           u1, v1 = 1, 0
    while v3 > 0:
        q=divmod(u3, v3)[0]
        u1, v1 = v1, u1 - v1*q
        u3, v3 = v3, u3 - v3*q
    while u1<0:
        u1 = u1 + v
    return u1
```

If you check the equivalent function in the [source](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Protocol/SecretSharing.py#L137-L152) of the more recent replacement library [`pycrytodome`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) there is a clear explanation that this is computing the [polynomial greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor):

```
    def inverse(self):
        """Return the inverse of this element in GF(2^128)."""

        # We use the Extended GCD algorithm
        # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor

        if self._value == 0:
            raise ValueError("Inversion of zero")

        r0, r1 = self._value, self.irr_poly
        s0, s1 = 1, 0
        while r1 > 0:
            q = _div_gf2(r0, r1)[0]
            r0, r1 = r1, r0 ^ _mult_gf2(q, r1)
            s0, s1 = s1, s0 ^ _mult_gf2(q, s1)
        return _Element(s0)
```

Comment: I tried to implement it to check it as you told me, but there was an error. The error is "invalid decimal literal" in 1L, 0L. What means 1L and 0L?

Comment: @howl as commented in my answer, this is **python 2** code, that is made possible using a compatibility tool that is imported in the code. Otherwise, the syntax in invalid in python 3. `1L` means `long` in python 2, which doesn't exist in python 3 since integers can have an arbitrary length. You should be able to remove `long` and `L` to "convert" to python 3.

Comment: The second algorithm is not a replacement for the first. The first is specifically for integers. The second algorithm is for, as it says, the polynomial inverse. Both are based on the extended Euclidean algorithm. In modern python (since ver 3.8), the inverse can be calculated by using the [built-in pow()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function. See https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/00a6287e55f5c086b0d76c23bfe19509f330435f/lib/Crypto/Util/number.py#L131